# Can machines communicate via serial port without having network adapters?

Tags: networking

In VMWare, I have two virtual machines which are connected to each other through a named pipe. Can they communicate with that serial port or do I need to enable the network adapters ?

Answer (score 0):

Configure VMWare to [connect the serial port of one VM with the serial port of another](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_devices_serial_2vms.html). This is the virtual equivalent of plugging a null modem cable into the serial ports of two physical computers. Then, setup a [null modem connection](http://mikebeach.org/2012/08/30/installing-and-configuring-a-ppp-null-modem-connection-on-windows-7/), where you network over PPP (Point-to-Point Protocol) just like the old analog modem days.

That said, why do you want to do this? Serial connections are very slow and are commonly used when a very simple, dumb, low level connection is needed. If you want to isolate traffic between two computers, create new virtual NICs on each and add them to the same, separate virtual subnet. This will be much faster, means you do not need to connect and disconnect over PPP and the existing VMWare management and monitoring tools work with it.